# Building and interpretation of regression models

Tags: regression, predictive-models, interpretation

Coming from the world of classification I struggle to understand how to properly build and interpret regression models.

Some tutorials only build models on the training data to make conclusions. Other tutorials try to fit the model on the test data before deriving conclusions. Most tutorials share the way they calculate various regression performance measures, such as MAE, RMSE, RAE, R^2 etc. Even though I understand how the calculation is performed and it typically looks at the difference between actual and predicted values, I still struggle to get the feeling of what these numbers are really saying. In contrast, in classification one can get a fairly good idea whether a model is good or not by simply looking at accuracy/precision/recall/AUC etc. depending on the dataset.

This brings me to two main questions:

1. What is an acceptable way of performing regression, i.e. is it enough to build a model on the training data and get its summary, or should you try to also fit this model on the testing data?
2. Depending on 1, now is the question of interpreting the model. Since a good R^2 doesn't necessarily mean a good model, and other measures mentioned above have their own caveats, I'm wondering to estimate how well the model is doing (i.e. I don't have the ground truth to compare my models with some others, since I engineered my own features and predict my own dependent variable which haven't been used before). Is there a single measure that can give you a fair idea about the model (like accuracy in classification)? If not, would the first step to interpretation be producing QQ-plots. Also, would it make sense to use Chi-square to compare predicted and actual values (or some other test for correlation)? To summarize, the question is: what is the generic procedure to interpret a regression model?

Comment: Welcome to CV. This is possibly a huge topic. Please be a bit more precise on what kind of "regression" you mean. In terms of the "regression vs. classification" the difference is a bit like determining a single value (classification) vs. the determination of a distribution (regression); e.g. for 1D.